# Listview item layout left toright

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How could I style a listview so items are added left to right then start a new row under that row? Example:

```
_____________
|1 2 4  5  6|
|7 8 9 10 11|
|12 13      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the `ItemsPanel` template, for your requirement, set the template as an `ItemsWrapGrid` and set its Orientation as `Horizontal`.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Works perfect thanks. I'd upvote this a billion times if I could.